# Remove duplicates based on some conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have two datasets: D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub>. D<sub>2</sub> is a left join from D<sub>1</sub> and a larger dataset which I will call D<sub>3</sub>. Although the key column of D<sub>2</sub> has the same number of unique elements than D<sub>1</sub>, it has some duplicates that I want to get rid of based on certain conditions.

There are two problems:

**1)** There are some rows full of NA values, except for the key value, and these rows are very important to me.

**2)** There are some other rows which may or may not be duplicated but doesn't match with my standard condition.

How can I remove these duplicates conditionally based on a hierarchy?

**Sample dataset:**

```
ID  Var
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   9
4   2
4   9
5   1
6   1
7   1
7   9
7   9
8   2
9  
10  1
```

**Expected dataset:**

```
ID  Var
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   2
9  
10  1
```

Comment: Do you want to select 1st row in each group? `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1L)` ?

Comment: `duplicated` works on single columns, too.

Comment: I don't have problems to identify the duplicates, my problem is to process the duplicates once identified.

Comment: (1) Your discussion of D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> and such seems superfluous and confusing. If it is relevant to have multiple tables, then ... please provide multiple tables and the context of why we need them to show what joining them does. (2) *"which may or may not be duplicated"* sounds ... squishy. What is your "standard condition"? What non-duplicating conditions are required to trigger or stop removal?

Answer (score 0):

`duplicated` does what you need.

```r
dat[!duplicated(dat$ID),]
#    ID Var
# 1   1   1
# 2   2   1
# 3   3   1
# 5   4   2
# 7   5   1
# 8   6   1
# 9   7   1
# 12  8   2
# 13  9  NA
# 14 10   1
```

As does something from the tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And data.table ...

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[ !duplicated(ID), ]
```

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Var
1   1
2   1
3   1
3   9
4   2
4   9
5   1
6   1
7   1
7   9
7   9
8   2
9   NA
10  1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say! We have a data.table below:

```
Library(data.table)
 df <- data.table(Name = c("JACK", "JOHN", "JACK", "ANNIE", "JOHN", "JACK"), 
                  Amount = c(30, 10, 20, 24, 5, 1))
```

In this case, I order by Name so it will be similar to your Id column. When I got the appropriate order, I will take only the first result

```
df[][order(Name, Amount)]
df[,.SD[1], by = Name]
```

## Output:

```
    Name Amount
1:  JACK     30
2:  JOHN     10
3: ANNIE     24
```

I hope this may help you.